# How to distribute a Swift Package with a private repository on GitLab?

Tags: swift, gitlab, package, swift-package-manager

I'm trying to distribute a Swift Package on a private repository on GitLab.
In the file Package.swift located at the root of the git repository, I'm trying to use the SSH connection but I have an error when I'm putting *"git@gitlab.com:myteam.my/path/-/raw/1.0.0/xcframework/1.0.0.zip"* as the URL of the binary target.
*error: invalid URL scheme for binary target 'MyTarget'; valid schemes are: 'https'*
So the only valid scheme is 'https'? I'm having trouble to use 'https' scheme, I'm allaying getting the following *error: failed downloading 'https://gitlab.com/myteam/my/path/-/raw/1.0.0/xcframework/1.0.0.zip' which is required by binary target 'MyTarget': /var/folders/t4/qd0rg_cj79xchv2_34xjfh_40000gn/T/CFNetworkDownload_C4T3iM.tmp doesn't exist in file system*. I was guessing the fact that the repository is private, SPM is not able to download the Swift Package except if it's using SSH.
Does anyone have any hints? I've seen people using URLs starting by *git@* in their Package.swift so I don't understand the error I get. Thank you.

Comment: The error message is very clear, IMHO. ;)  And yes, there are some limitations when downloading binary assets. You should provide more information in order to get help. You may look here for more details: https://forums.swift.org/t/spm-support-basic-auth-for-non-git-binary-dependency-hosts/37878

Answer (score 0):

Try using [gitfront.io](https://gitfront.io) which will create public link for your private Git repo where you host your SPM package. Works only if such solution is not forbidden in your company for security reasons. For more info you can also check  [this gitfront setup tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LuxTnUMP5b0). Hopefully it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

I have received the same error with a public repo. It appears that Swift Packages are not yet fully supported by gitlab, but are open to community contributions. [gitlab docs](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/packages/package_registry/#supported-package-managers:%7E:text=This%20table%20lists%20unsupported%20package%20manager%20formats%20that%20we%20are%20accepting%20contributions%20for)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your Xcode isn't using its built-in distribution of Git:

```
defaults write com.apple.dt.Xcode IDEPackageSupportUseBuiltinSCM YES
```

Then you can put the following in your git config:

```
[url "git@github.com:"]
    insteadOf = https://github.com/
```

This effectively forces git to do a find-replace for ssh instead of https. You could also have it point to a different git host if you wanted it to.